# Axios not cancelling requests

Tags: reactjs, axios, cancellation

I am trying to cancel an Axios request that I made in CompnentDidMount() in ComponentWillUnmount() as everyone says to do. However it does not seem to be working. Like at all.

Here is the relevant code from my project:

```
        //Make API call
        this.setState({ isMounted: true });
        this.axiosCancelSource = Axios.CancelToken.source();
        var result;
        result = await Axios("/api/product", { cancelToken: this.axiosCancelSource.token });
        if (this.state.isMounted) {
            this.setState({ products: result.data.products });
        }

        
        //this.updateList();


    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.setState({ isMounted: false });
        this.axiosCancelSource.cancel();
    }
```

and here is a snapshot of my network tab in Chrome DevTools:
[Network Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHWas.png)

I'm not sure if this is the issue, but it seems like my component mounts and unmount once very quickly then mounts again. I'm not quite sure the cause of this either or if it might be affecting the cancellation of my axios requests. I've scoured the internet for hours trying to solve this, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount

> You should not call `setState()` in `componentWillUnmount()` because the component will never be re-rendered. Once a component instance is unmounted, it will never be mounted again.

You should remove the `setState` from unmount for that weird behavior you mentioned. And then you can verify your axios cancel. However, understand what you are doing - you are trying to cancel any axios call **IF ANY IN PROGRESS** while unmounting. You need to simulate a long running network call and unmount to test it.

Comment: I will try and take the setState out of willUnmount, however I had it like that before and it still behaved the same way. As far as simulating a long running network call, I'm not sure what you mean. In the network tab on the dev tools, those network calls just say pending until they finish at which point they say how long they took all at once. They usually take 30 seconds as I havent optimized at all yet.

Comment: I mean, for you to test cancelling existing API, this code might not be sufficient as cancelling happens on unmount. If you want to see how that works, try unmounting the component by rendering null. That's all.